# Sorting an HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

The following code sorts an HTML table with JavaScript (without using any external libraries like jQuery). Are there any shortcomings or possible improvements I could make?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=Windows-1252">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var people, asc1 = 1,
            asc2 = 1,
            asc3 = 1;
        window.onload = function () {
            people = document.getElementById("people");
        }

        function sort_table(tbody, col, asc) {
            var rows = tbody.rows,
                rlen = rows.length,
                arr = new Array(),
                i, j, cells, clen;
            // fill the array with values from the table
            for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
                cells = rows[i].cells;
                clen = cells.length;
                arr[i] = new Array();
                for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
                    arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
                }
            }
            // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
            arr.sort(function (a, b) {
                return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1 * asc);
            });
            // replace existing rows with new rows created from the sorted array
            for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
                rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>" + arr[i].join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: none;
        }
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 4px 16px;
            font-family: Times New Roman;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #C8C8C8;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th onclick="sort_table(people, 0, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1;">Name</th>
                <th onclick="sort_table(people, 1, asc2); asc2 *= -1; asc3 = 1; asc1 = 1;">Surname</th>
                <th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc3); asc3 *= -1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1;">Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="people">
            <tr>
                <td>Raja</td>
                <td>Dey</td>
                <td>18</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mamata</td>
                <td>Sharma</td>
                <td>20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Avijit</td>
                <td>Sharma</td>
                <td>21</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sharanya</td>
                <td>Dutta</td>
                <td>26</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nabin</td>
                <td>Roy</td>
                <td>27</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the code otherwise working? If you're looking for just feedback, you should post to [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: Why not use Jquery. You can use tablesorter plugin. http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

Comment: His code is working (it only had a misconfiguration on jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGf45/1/) ) and he is asking for performance tips. @Anup :  `(without any external library like JQuery)`

Comment: Instead of `-1 * asc`, use just `-asc`.

Comment: Why not using UTF-8 instead of this weird charset?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To speed up the sorting you first have to find what is consuming time. In your case the slower part of your code is:

```
for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
    rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>"+arr[i].join("</td><td>")+"</td>";
}
```

The reason is that the DOM elaboration is time consuming for the browser.

Here's an updated version that minimizes the access to the DOM:

```
function sort_table(tbody, col, asc){
    var rows = tbody.rows, rlen = rows.length, arr = new Array(), i, j, cells, clen;
    // fill the array with values from the table
    for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    clen = cells.length;
    arr[i] = new Array();
        for(j = 0; j < clen; j++){
        arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
    arr.sort(function(a, b){
        return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1*asc);
    });
    for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
        arr[i] = "<td>"+arr[i].join("</td><td>")+"</td>";
    }
    tbody.innerHTML = "<tr>"+arr.join("</tr><tr>")+"</tr>";
}
```

Proof: http://jsperf.com/table-sorting-stack-overflow

Comment: why is your method slower than op s method on firefox 61 osx 10.14 lol

Answer (score 6):

I ran into some trouble with **ProGM**'s solution.

1. It didn't take numerical sorting into account.
2. IE did NOT like setting this line: `tbody.innerHTML = "<tr>"+arr.join("</tr><tr>")+"</tr>";`
3. It would destroy any attributes assigned to any part of the table (css class names and etc)

I have made adjustments:

```
function sort_table(tbody, col, asc)
{
    var rows = tbody.rows;
    var rlen = rows.length;
    var arr = new Array();
    var i, j, cells, clen;
    // fill the array with values from the table
    for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++)
    {
        cells = rows[i].cells;
        clen = cells.length;
        arr[i] = new Array();
      for(j = 0; j < clen; j++) { arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML; }
    }
    // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
    arr.sort(function(a, b)
    {
        var retval=0;
        var fA=parseFloat(a[col]);
        var fB=parseFloat(b[col]);
        if(a[col] != b[col])
        {
            if((fA==a[col]) && (fB==b[col]) ){ retval=( fA > fB ) ? asc : -1*asc; } //numerical
            else { retval=(a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1*asc;}
        }
        return retval;      
    });
    for(var rowidx=0;rowidx<rlen;rowidx++)
    {
        for(var colidx=0;colidx<arr[rowidx].length;colidx++){ tbody.rows[rowidx].cells[colidx].innerHTML=arr[rowidx][colidx]; }
    }
}
```

To address point #1, I added in the calls to `parseFloat()` and then compared the result the original value (You change to checking if it produces `NaN` instead). If both values are numeric, they compared via numerical preference and not by their string versions.

For points #2 and #3, I solved it via the same set of code. Instead of destroying the whole table body by setting the `innerHTML`, I change the individual cell contents to the new sorted values:

```
for(var rowidx=0;rowidx<rlen;rowidx++)
{
    for(var colidx=0;colidx<arr[rowidx].length;colidx++)
    { 
        tbody.rows[rowidx].cells[colidx].innerHTML=arr[rowidx][colidx]; 
    }
}
```

That only works if yours all have the same number of columns, but if you do not, sorting is much more complex anyway.

Comment: will you explain the adjustments please and how they overcome the issues that you found?

Comment: Can do, I also found a mistake in mine.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the pure JS for sorting table data. I used first column which holds numbers. You have to modify **column index and condition statement** as per your requirements. I hope that solves your problem...

```
    // Table data sorting starts....
    function sortData() {
        // Read table body node.
        var tableData = document.getElementById('data_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody').item(0);

        // Read table row nodes.
        var rowData = tableData.getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

        for(var i = 0; i < rowData.length - 1; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < rowData.length - (i + 1); j++) {

                //Swap row nodes if short condition matches
                if(parseInt(rowData.item(j).getElementsByTagName('td').item(0).innerHTML) > parseInt(rowData.item(j+1).getElementsByTagName('td').item(0).innerHTML)) {
                    tableData.insertBefore(rowData.item(j+1),rowData.item(j));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Table data sorting ends....
```

HTML Table:

```
<table id="data_table" width="200" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="100">01</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>eee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>fff</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML Table: Sorted

```
<table id="data_table" width="200" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="100">01</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>eee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>fff</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3t4/2/).

Comment: This whole answer is all jquery.  Although I think it's great you answered, the OP was asking specifically for non jquery solutions.

Comment: Here you go. Pure JS code for sorting HTML nodes. You can see the demo on given link.

Answer (score 3):

I was working on a table sorting script in ES6 today, researching the various methods to determine the most efficient. I dismissed working with the `innerHTML` property out of hand, from [previous research](https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild/400), instead trying a series of options using:

1. [`insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) & [`deleteRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow)
2. [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) & [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)
3. [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) / [`prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) & [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

with the latter coming out as the fastest in my tests on tables with a large number (>5000) of rows.

Given that, here is the code I came up with, integrated into your use case.

```js
(()=>{
    let people=document.getElementById("people"),
        thead=people.previousElementSibling,
        rows=[...people.rows],
        orders=[1,1,-1],
        sort=(col)=>{
            let x=rows.length;
            rows.sort((a,b)=>{
                let i=a.children[col].firstChild.nodeValue,
                    j=b.children[col].firstChild.nodeValue;
                return i===j?0:i>j?orders[col]:-orders[col];
            });
            orders[col]*=-1;
            while(people.lastChild)
                people.lastChild.remove();
            while(x--)
                people.prepend(rows[x]);
        };
    thead.addEventListener("click",event=>{
        let target=event.target;
        if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase()==="th")
            sort(target.cellIndex);
    },0);
})();
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:none;
}
th,td{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:4px 16px;
  font-family:Times New Roman;
  font-size:24px;
  text-align:left;
}
th{
  background-color:#C8C8C8;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="people">
    <tr>
      <td>Raja</td>
      <td>Dey</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mamata</td>
      <td>Sharma</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Avijit</td>
      <td>Sharma</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sharanya</td>
      <td>Dutta</td>
      <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nabin</td>
      <td>Roy</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just converted your script into Javascript of "nowadays", I used ".tHead" on the table object instead of previousElementSibling and I added a null check because a.children[col].firstChild.nodeValue can be null when a cell is empty. I'm going to compute the content of "orders".

Comment: prepend is an experimental feature not supported by Microsoft Edge. Array.from() isn't supported by Microsoft Internet Explorer.

Comment: I modified the loop in order to use appendChild() instead of prepend(), I used removeChild() instead of remove() and I replaced Array.from by a simple creation of an array and a loop to copy the elements one by one. Now, it works in Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome & Chromium, Microsoft Edge and Microsoft Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved version based on Plater's anwser. Just in case there is DOM elements inside of `td` tags, the code gets the last child of the cell and get the value, and apply a customized filter to it.

**Note:** The customized filter here is just an example, and also you don't need to get the last child of the `td` tags, and it can be any child of your use case.

```js
function sortTable(tbody, col, asc) {
  var rows = tbody.rows;
  var rlen = rows.length;
  var arr = new Array();
  var i, j, cells, clen;
  /* fill the array with values from the table */
  for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    clen = cells.length;
    arr[i] = new Array();
    for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
    }
  }
  /* sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc) */
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var retval = 0;
    var aVal = getDomValue(a[col]);
    var bVal = getDomValue(b[col]);
    var fA = parseFloat(aVal);
    var fB = parseFloat(bVal);
    if (aVal != bVal) {

      if ((fA == aVal) && (fB == bVal)) {
        retval = (fA > fB) ? asc : -1 * asc;
      } // Numerical
      else {
        retval = (aVal > bVal) ? asc : -1 * asc;
      } // String
    }
    return retval;
  });
  /* fill the table with sorted values */
  for (var rowidx = 0; rowidx < rlen; rowidx++) {
    for (var colidx = 0; colidx < arr[rowidx].length; colidx++) {
      tbody.rows[rowidx].cells[colidx].innerHTML = arr[rowidx][colidx];
    }
  }

}

function getDomValue(domString) {
  var value;
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var element = parser.parseFromString(domString, 'text/xml');
  var content = element.lastChild.innerHTML;

  // Custom filter just in case if there is elements inside of the td.
  // I made two filters to standardize numbers like '$20,000', also I
  // treat whereas ' ' space as '0'
  if (content === ' ') content = content.replace(' ', '0');
  if (content.indexOf('$') !== -1) {
    content = content.replace('$', '');
    content = content.replace(',', '');
  }
  value = isNaN(parseFloat(content)) ? content : parseFloat(content);
  return value;
}
```